# Integrating button to launch SMS in Wix site, issue with iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, velo

I'm having issues integrating a button to launch SMS on a users device because Wix has only html iframe integration, which I'm sure is the issue that won't allow the button to launch with a single press for both iOS and android. iOS has to be long-pressed and droid is single press, in both cases they open up an "options menu" rather than go straight to SMS. Why I think it's the iframe is because it doesn't have the same issue when it's not an iframe html. Does anyone have any suggestions or experience with this issue, which is being able to launch directly to SMS (with not options menu) using iframe html. Thank you

This is the site www.blacjk.com and the orangish button is the "button to launch SMS"